# How to detect if word is camelcased or not?

Tags: java, string, camelcasing

> identify if the word is correctly camelcased when a set containing list of words is given.
> isMyWordCamelCased - True
> ismyWordCamelCased - False

```
("isMyWordCamelCased", ["cased", "my", "is", "word", "camel", ])
```

Here is my answer but I need help for last word "Cased" my loop finishing at "Case"

```
public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "isMyWordCamelCased";

        int counter = 0;

        String[] arr = {"cased", "my", "is", "word", "camel"};

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
        ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String s : arrayList) {
            if (str.startsWith(s)) {
                arrayList2.add(0, s);
            } else {
                String temp1 = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
                arrayList2.add(0, temp1);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.length(); j++) {
                String temp = (str.substring(i, j));

                if (arrayList2.contains(str.substring(i,j))){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (counter == arr.length) {
            System.out.println("word is camel case");
        } else {
            System.out.println("word is NOT camel case");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you going to run into an issue when j = str.length in your last for loop?

Comment: Your description of the problem implies you are interested in knowing if *A* word conforms. But your code seems to be processing a list and then printing information about *THAT* word. That's confusing considering the code you show. If you want to know if *EACH* word conforms, then write a boolean function that returns the conforming truth, then simply iterate over each element in the list printing truth within the body of the loop; not after the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

From the given description, it may help to loop around the string by each character and storing words in another list. Something like this might be useful:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "isMyWordCamelCased";
        String[] arr = {"cased", "my", "is", "word", "camel"};
        if(str == null || Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(0))){
            System.out.println(false);
            return;
        }
        List<String> resArr = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder tempValue = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i< str.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))){
                resArr.add(tempValue.toString().toLowerCase());
                tempValue = new StringBuilder(""+str.charAt(i));
            }else{
                tempValue.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        if(!"".equals(tempValue.toString())){
            resArr.add(tempValue.toString().toLowerCase());
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).containsAll(resArr));
    }
```